# Collapsible tabs in power apps portal sites

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, powerapps-portal

I want to create a collapsible tab in the power apps pages portal site

I have tried with some java script code but not able to set it properly
I want to build a collapsible tab in power pages portal site to be easily managed site